# The Torn Score Sheet

Tags: chess

I found half of a chess score sheet lying on one of the tables at the recent tournament I attended. It was ripped in half at the middle so only White's moves were visible. I was wondering if it would be possible for you to reconstruct Black's moves. (Note: The moves aren't necessarily good ones.)

> 1. Nf3
> 2. Nxg5
> 3. Nxf7
> 4. Nd6+
> 5. Nf5
> 6. Nxd4
> 7. c3
> 8. cxd4
> 9. Kxf2
> 10. Qa4+
> 11. Qxb5+
> 12. Qd5+
> 13. d3
> 14. Bxh6
> 15. Bxg7
> 16. Qxd7+
> 17. Qf5+
> 18. Qf8#

Partial answers are allowed, as always. Good luck! (I have no idea how difficult this is, it could be solved in minutes or days.)

Comment: I'm gunna try and work this out when I get home from work in a couple hours, looks like it's gunna take some doodling. (also I'm unfamiliar with chess notation so there's that to learn too)

Comment: @AHKieran I'll post a partial that may help with that last part. :)

Comment: Pretty sure Black's first move is terrible, at least :P

Comment: From my thinking thus far, I don't think there is one definitive answer. I believe black's 2nd and 3rd moves can be interchangeable.

Comment: @AHKieran There isn't intended to be one definitive answer.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu can you confirm if move 16 is completely correct as written (see my answer for spoilers). I think I could get this done if black had one more move....

Comment: @El-Guest it is correct as written. Went over my answer to make sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Feedback

This was a really interesting puzzle and was enjoyable to work! $+1$ from me indeed! It seems like moves $3$ and $13$ are heavily interchangeable, so long as they don't prevent checkmate down the road. Again, very nice puzzle!

---

### Answer

The moves on white's half of the board are in [algebraic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) form for chess. You have to look at it from the perspective of:

> Queen to F4, Captures Rook, Check. = QxF4+

This is more in the realm of mental chess where no board is needed; I have always wanted to attempt it against someone, and this is pretty close! So if I could I would give more up-votes!

I believe that black is a novice player and isn't really thinking too far ahead with his/her movements. Thus leading to an eventual defeat dealt by white.

[image: Final Board]

---

My theory (White :: Black):

> 1. Knight to F3 :: Pawn to G5
>  2. Knight to G5 (Captures Pawn) :: Pawn to D5
>  3. Knight to F7 (Captures Pawn) :: Bishop to G7
>  4. Knight to D6 (Check) :: King to D7
>  5. Knight to F5 :: Pawn to D4
>  6. Knight to D4 (Captures Pawn):: Queen to F8
>  7. Pawn to C3 :: Bishop to D4 (Captures Knight)
>  8. Pawn to D4 (Captures Bishop) :: Queen to F2 (Captures Pawn, Check)
>  9. King to F2 (Captures Queen, Release Check) :: Knight to H6
>  10. Queen to A4 (Check):: Pawn to B5 (Release Check)
>  11. Queen to B5 (Captures Pawn, Check) :: King to D8 (Release Check)
>  12. Queen to D5 (Check):: King to E8 (Release Check)
>  13. Pawn to D3 :: Rook to G8
>  14. Bishop to H6 (Captures Knight) :: Rook to G7
>  15. Bishop to G7 (Captures Rook):: Bishop to D7
>  16. Queen to D7 (Captures Bishop, Check):: King to F7
>  17. Queen to F5 (Check):: King to G8
>  18. Queen to F8 (Checkmate)

Special thanks to @ExcitedRaichu for pointing out that move $3$ was the biggest incorrect move, followed by move $13$.

Comment: C3 and D3 refer to pawn movements. See [this guide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) for notation.

Comment: This is super useful, but yeah, c3 and d3 refer to a pawn moving to those squares, the x refers to a capture, + is check, and # is checkmate. If you could add these words to your white move list then that would be even more useful :D

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Comment: On move 4 Kf7 is illegal because that square is also guarded by the knight.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! I am currently working this in steps and @ExcitedRaichu I have to say this is a good one. I figured out all of the above while working through; I'll be giving very little feedback for a while as I work this! :)

Comment: i think move 4 should be Ke7 which means that on one of the previous moves, the pawn at e7 would have moved to e6 or e5

Comment: I've already adjusted, please give about 30 more minutes prior to providing further feedback. There's a move on black's bishop that I'm trying to figure out here. Somehow it ends up at F2 putting the king in check and I can see it, but there is a lot going on and I'm having to visualize it lol

Comment: @PerpetualJ: Just to hopefully prevent you from falling down a rabbit hole: Knight to D4 (move 6) needs to be a capture.

Comment: Good work! I'm gunna crack out the chessboard when I get home and simulate your moves :D

Comment: You already have Knight to H6, so you can’t move the Pawn there after

Comment: I was about to say the exact same thing. XD

Comment: @PerpetualJ the one thing you’re missing is white’s play of Bishop to G7 means that the Black King is forced to F7 instead of F8. But since there’s no piece on E7, the white Queen on D7 would have that as check as well. The only valid move is to capture the Queen from that position.

Comment: @PerpetualJ you can't Qh4 on move 6 if the pawn is still on e7.

Comment: This still doesn’t address my issue — plus you have the pawn on e7 moving to e5 on move 3. Kf8 on move 16 is inadmissible due to Bxg7 on move 15.

Comment: @El-Guest Once again, you said my answer a minute before I was going to. lol

Comment: @PerpetualJ that would be fine btw

Comment: Do you play chess? I would like to verse you, if I could :P

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a partial answer, although part of me is not sure because it relies on one of the moves provided being wrong, I think:

> 1. Nf3 **g5** 
>  2. Nxg5 d5 
>  3. Nxf7 e5 
>  4. Nd6+ Kd7 
>  5. Nf5 d4 
>  6. Nxd4 Qh4 
>  7. c3 exd4 
>  8. cxd4 Qxf2+ 
>  9. Kxf2 Ne7 
>  10. Qa4+ b5 
>  11. Qxb5+ Kd8 
>  12. Qd5+ Ke8 
>  13. d3 h6 
>  14. Bxh6 Bg7 
>  15. Bxg7  <strike>Rh7</strike>  Bd7 
>  16. ***Qxd7+*** Kf7 
>  17. Qf5+ Kg8 
>  18. Qf8# (but this is not mate...)