# The Torn Score Sheet- #2

Tags: chess

I really enjoyed the reaction to my previous puzzle, [The Torn Score Sheet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/the-torn-score-sheet), and I'd like to do another one. This one's a little shorter and easier, and once again it's White's moves only. Good luck!

> 1. e4
> 2. d4
> 3. Qxd4
> 4. Bc4
> 5. Bxe6
> 6. Qxc5+
> 7. Qd5+
> 8. Qe5#

Good luck!

Comment: This was an interesting little puzzle!!

Comment: I agree with @El-Guest; I think I'll write one myself! Good puzzle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it’s

> 1. e4 Nc6 
>  2. d4 Nxd4 
>  3. Qxd4 e6 
>  4. Bc4 Ke7 
>  
>  5. Bxe6 c5 
>  6. Qxc5+ Kxe6 
>  7. Qd5+ Ke7 
>  8. Qe5#

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this looks like a Danish Gambit on white's part.

> Pawn to E4 :: Pawn to C5
>  Pawn to D4 :: Pawn to D4 (Captures Pawn)
>  Queen to D4 (Captures Pawn) :: Pawn to E6
>  Bishop to C4 :: Bishop to C5
>  Bishop to E6 (Captures Pawn) :: King to E7
>  Queen to C5 (Captures Bishop, Check) :: King to E6 (Captures Bishop)
>  Queen to D5 (Check) :: King to E7
>  Queen to E5 (Checkmate)

The finished board:

> [image]

Comment: I do enjoy watching your workings on this!! You don’t often get to see works in progress but I love your logic ability!!

Comment: @El-Guest Thanks! I really enjoy chess and wish I had a better skill level with it. Practice makes perfect!

Comment: It does help to have a chess board in front of you, or at least (what I use since I don’t have one handy) a sheet of paper where I record piece movements by erasing and rewriting the symbols/letters! Looking forward to seeing your puzzle!

Comment: Unfortunately the bishop is no longer on f8 and black is therefore not checkmated.