# The Torn Score Sheet #3

Tags: chess

Yep, I've got another torn score-sheet here for y'all. This one seems especially wrecked; some of even White's moves are illegible. Still, it's possible to put the game together. Good luck!

> 1. d4
> 2. illegible
> 3. Nxe5
> 4. Qxd4
> 5. illegible
> 6. illegible
> 7. Bxg7
> 8. Qg4+
> 9. Qh4+
> 10. Nxf7
> 11. illegible
> 12. illegible
> 13. exd5
> 14. Bc4
> 15. Kxd1
> 16. Ng5+
> 17. Qxh7#

Previous Puzzle Links

[The Torn Score Sheet- #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73396/the-torn-score-sheet-2)

[The Torn Score Sheet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/the-torn-score-sheet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heavily borrowing from @Evargalo's answer (please give them an upvote or two or all of them, they deserve it for a wonderful answer!), but I think I might have it:

1. > d4 e5
2. > Nf3 Bc5
3. > Nxe5 Bxd4
4. > Qxd4 Nh6
5. > Bxh6 d5
6. > Nd2 **Ke7**
7. > Bxg7 **Ke6**
8. > Qg4+ Ke7
9. > Qh4+ Ke8
10. > Nxf7 Bg4
11. > e4 Bd1
12. > Nf3 Kxf7
13. > exd5 **Rf8**
14. > Bc4 **a6**
15. > Kxd1 **a5**
16. > Ng5+ Kg8
17. > Qxh7#

Comment: Nice correction, congrats!

Answer (score 5):

One suggestion, but I believe there are many answers:

1. > d4 e5
2. > Nf3 Bc5
3. > Nxe5 Bxd4
4. > Qxd4 Nh6
5. > Bxh6 d5
6. > Nd2 Kd7
7. > Bxg7 Rf8
8. > Qg4+ Ke7
9. > Qh4+ Ke8
10. > Nxf7 Bg4
11. > e4 Bd1
12. > Nf3 Kxf7
13. > exd5 a.l.
14. > Bc4 a.l.
15. > Kxd1 a.l.
16. > Ng5+ Kg8
17. > Qxh7#

Edit: as pointed in comments, Black's 6th move is illegal. I have to reconsider.

Edit 2: The correction is provided in the accepted answer by El-Guest.

Comment: Close, but black's sixth move is illegal

Comment: Definitely +1 from me for a great answer! :D

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Ouch! Embarrassing... I suppose you did it on purpose so that we have to send the bK to the center of the board, maybe e4. Great problem.