# A Scrambled Game

Tags: chess

This was inspired by my earlier puzzles, the [Torn Scoresheet series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/the-torn-score-sheet).

In the following chess game, exactly one letter or number in each move (White or Black) is either exactly 1 higher or 1 lower than they should be (i.e. if the correct move is e4, it could be written as e3, d4, f4, or e5.) Letters representing pieces (R, N, B, K, Q) will not be any higher or lower. Captrues, checks, and checkmates will be in their original position. Once again, your goal is to reconstruct the original game.

Good luck!

> 1. d4 e6
> 2. Qe3 Ng6
> 3. Nd3 Bb5
> 4. Bd4 Qd7
> 5. c4 d5
> 6. Bd3 Bg5
> 7. Qh3 0-0
> 8. Nf4 exd5
> 9. Nxe4 Bxe4
> 10. Bxd5 Nbc7
> 11. Bxg6 Nxg6
> 12. 0-0 Nxe5
> 13. Rge1 Bf6
> 14. f4 c5
> 15. Ba3 b6
> 16. fxe3 Bxe3
> 17. Nxe5 dxe5
> 18. Qg4 Ree8
> 19. d3 Rae8
> 20. Bb2 f4
> 21. Qxf4 Qe6
> 22. Qxe3 Qd5+
> 23. Kg1 Rxe5
> 24. Rxd4 Rd3
> 25. Re1 Rxd2
> 26. Rd8+ Qf7
> 27. Rfxg8#

Comment: Would you like to clarify what you mean by "Captures, checks, and checkmates will be *in their original position*"? Does this mean that the locations given for those are correct? Or that the x,+,# indicators are attached to the correct moves? Or something else?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan they are attached to the correct moves, in the correct places.

Comment: So those moves *don't* have locations displaced by 1 on each axis, but all other moves *do*?

Comment: Er, sorry, I mean by 1 on *one* axis.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Every move has 1 off on 1 axis. I was just saying that I didn't alter or mix around +, x, and #

Comment: Well, this is annoying. I thought I could reconstruct just about everything unambiguously, aside from a couple of moves that could go a couple of different ways without changing anything ... but then *right at the end* everything fails to work and I can't find a consistent last move. So presumably I have made some error with subtle long-range consequences earlier in the game...

Comment: Ah, wait a minute, I think I see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following is a possible reconstruction. (It looks to me as if some moves can be reconstructed in more than one way, without making much difference to the game. I am not more than 70% confident that I haven't erred in a way that makes the following not a valid solution after all.)

> 1. e4 e5 2. Qf3 Nf6 3. Nc3 Bc5 4. Bc4 Qe7
>  5. d4 d6 6. Be3 Bg4 7. Qg3 O-O 8. Nf3 exd4
>  9. Nxd4 Bxd4 10. Bxd4 Nbd7 11. Bxf6 Nxf6 12. O-O Nxe4
>  13. Rfe1 Bf5 14. f3 d5 15. Bb3 a6 16. fxe4 Bxe4
>  17. Nxe4 dxe4 18. Qf4 Rfe8 19. c3 Rad8 20. Bc2 f5
>  21. Qxf5 Qd6 22. Qxe4 Qc5+ 23. Kh1 Rxe4 24. Rxe4 Rd2
>  25. Rf1 Rxc2 26. Re8+ Qf8 27. Rfxf8#